# IndexError: shape mismatch: indexing arrays could not be broadcast together with shapes (2,) (9,)

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, array-broadcasting

In this part of code:

```
for k, v in Candidates.iteritems():
        Device = XDevice[XDevice[:, 1] == k, np.array([2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10])]
```

I've this IndexError:

```
shape mismatch: indexing arrays could not be broadcast together with shapes (2,) (9,)
```

Comment: Hello. Can you give some info on `XDevice` ?

Comment: Have a look at https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.broadcasting.html

Comment: Where XDevices is a np.array containing:
[[  26.   58.    3.   12.    4.   -1.   21.   32.    1.    0.  131.]
 [  24.   30.    1.   24.    3.   -1.   70.  113.    5.    1.  188.]
 [  40.    8.    2.    0.    9.    0.   33.    0.   14.    1.  201.]
...
]

Comment: Look at the `shape` of every item in the problem line.  Test the smallest conbinations.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you cannot do the selection on both dimensions at the same time !

Split it in two lines :

```
for k, v in Candidates.iteritems():
        Device_ = XDevice[XDevice[:, 1] == k,:]
        Device =  Device_[:,np.array([2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10])
```

Comment: Thanks with your answer I fix the problem ;)

Comment: Now I've another problem in the same code :row = np.concatenate((Device, Cookie))
ValueError: all the input arrays must have same number of dimensions

Comment: I don't have information on Cookie, but it should be a 2dimensional array with the shape of the non-concatenated dimension equal to the one of Device !
Otherwise you'll get an error